# Struct segmentation fault when adding values to struct members

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault

I'm getting a segmentation fault at `new_session->sid = sid;`. Can't figure out why.

pseudo sessions_list.h

```
typedef char *user;

typedef int sessionid;

struct session_list {
    sessionid sid;
    user user;
    struct session_list *next;
};
typedef struct session_list *session;

session insert_session(session, sessionid, user);
session search_session(session, sessionid);
session delete_session(session, sessionid);
void show_session_list(session);
```

Pseudo .c to explain the problem:

```
session sessions;

main(){

get_session_1_svc("this user");

}

extern  sessionid * get_session_1_svc(user * usr){
    static sessionid sid = 0;
    sid = clock();
    insert_session(sessions,sid,*usr);

    return &sid;
}

session insert_session(session session_list,sessionid sid, user user){
    session new_session = (session) (sizeof(struct session_list));
    new_session->sid = sid;
    new_session->user = user;
    new_session->next = session_list->next;
    session_list->next = new_session;
    return new_session;
}
```

Comment: Please post real code. "*Pseudo .c*" is useless when asking about a segmentation fault.

Comment: You will want to review: [Is it a good idea to **typedef** pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers).

Comment: @dxiv the get_session_1_svc gets called over RPC from a client onto the server. the client sends its username as a char* over to the method get_session1_svc. thats all I changed. as well as insert_Session is in a different .c file and the .h is included in the server file where get_session_1_svc is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, no wonder you are. This line:

```
session new_session = (session) (sizeof(struct session_list));
```

Is completely invalid. The fact that you are forcibly casting to `session` hides the error, but you are basically assigning an arbitrary number to a pointer.

I suspect that you actually want to *allocate memory*. In such case, you would do the following:

```
session new_session = malloc(sizeof(struct session_list));
```